# How to switch the data onClick of button?

Tags: java, android, button

I have a list of items of object. I am creating dynamic buttons as per the size of a list using for loop.

I am showing some data when its the first item of the loop. Now /i want to switch the data when I will click the buttons.

Buttons will have the numbers of the item, if three items are present in the list , three buttons are there named one, two, three.

So if I click on first I want to show data of first item, if second clicked data of second item respectively.

I tried to do it, but I am not able to get the result.

```
 @Override
public void doPostExecute(List<Payment> list1)
{

    list.addAll(list1);

    for(final Payment payment : list) {

        i++;

        Button myButton = new Button(getActivity());

        LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(60,30);
        linear_buttons.addView(myButton, lp);

        myButton.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit_button);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (payment.getPaidAmount() != null && !payment.getPaidAmount().equals("null"))
                    txt_paid.setText("$" + payment.getPaidAmount());

                if (payment.getProductStatus() != null && !payment.getProductStatus().equals("null")) {
                    if (payment.getProductStatus().equals("1")) {
                        txt_status.setText(getString(R.string.paid));
                        button_complain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        button_more.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    } else if (payment.getProductStatus().equals("0")) {
                        txt_status.setText(getString(R.string.unPaid));
                        button_complain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        button_more.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else if (payment.getProductStatus().equals("5")) {
                        txt_status.setText(getString(R.string.processing));
                        button_complain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        button_more.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else if (payment.getProductStatus().equals("6")) {
                        button_complain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        button_more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        txt_status.setText(getString(R.string.releasedStatus));
                    } else if (payment.getProductStatus().equals("8")) {
                        txt_status.setText(getString(R.string.disputeStatus));
                        button_complain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        button_more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else if (payment.getProductStatus().equals("9")) {
                        txt_status.setText(getString(R.string.disputeResolvedStatus));
                        button_complain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        button_more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else if (payment.getProductStatus().equals("2")) {
                        txt_status.setText(getString(R.string.completedStatus));
                        button_complain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        button_more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    if (payment.getTpAmount() != null && !payment.getTpAmount().equals("null")) {

                        String amount = String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", Double.parseDouble(payment.getTpAmount()));
                        txt_tp_amount.setText("$" + amount);
                    }

                    if (payment.getCommission() != null && !payment.getCommission().equals("null")) {

                        String amount = String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", Double.parseDouble(payment.getCommission()));
                        txt_comission.setText("$" + amount);
                    }

                    if (payment.getTax() != null && !payment.getTax().equals("null")) {

                        String amount = String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", Double.parseDouble(payment.getTax()));
                        txt_tax.setText("$" + amount);
                    }

                    if (payment.getPayeEmail() != null && !payment.getPayeEmail().equals("null")) {

                        txt_payee_email.setText(payment.getPayeEmail());
                    }
                    if (payment.getPayerEmail() != null && !payment.getPayerEmail().equals("null")) {

                        txt_payer_email.setText(payment.getPayerEmail());
                    }

                    if (payment.getPayerName() != null && !payment.getPayerName().equals("null")) {

                        txt_payer_name.setText(payment.getPayerName());
                    }

                    if (payment.getVendorId() != null && !payment.getVendorId().equals("null")) {

                        txt_vendor_id.setText(payment.getVendorId());
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        if(i==1) {

            if (payment.getPaidAmount() != null && !payment.getPaidAmount().equals("null"))
                txt_paid.setText("$" + payment.getPaidAmount());

            if (payment.getProductStatus() != null && !payment.getProductStatus().equals("null")) {
                if (payment.getProductStatus().equals("1")) {
                    txt_status.setText(getString(R.string.paid));
                    button_complain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    button_more.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                } else if (payment.getProductStatus().equals("0")) {
                    txt_status.setText(getString(R.string.unPaid));
                    button_complain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    button_more.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else if (payment.getProductStatus().equals("5")) {
                    txt_status.setText(getString(R.string.processing));
                    button_complain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    button_more.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else if (payment.getProductStatus().equals("6")) {
                    button_complain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    button_more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txt_status.setText(getString(R.string.releasedStatus));
                } else if (payment.getProductStatus().equals("8")) {
                    txt_status.setText(getString(R.string.disputeStatus));
                    button_complain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    button_more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (payment.getProductStatus().equals("9")) {
                    txt_status.setText(getString(R.string.disputeResolvedStatus));
                    button_complain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    button_more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (payment.getProductStatus().equals("2")) {
                    txt_status.setText(getString(R.string.completedStatus));
                    button_complain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    button_more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                if (payment.getTpAmount() != null && !payment.getTpAmount().equals("null")) {

                    String amount = String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", Double.parseDouble(payment.getTpAmount()));
                    txt_tp_amount.setText("$" + amount);
                }

                if (payment.getCommission() != null && !payment.getCommission().equals("null")) {

                    String amount = String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", Double.parseDouble(payment.getCommission()));
                    txt_comission.setText("$" + amount);
                }

                if (payment.getTax() != null && !payment.getTax().equals("null")) {

                    String amount = String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", Double.parseDouble(payment.getTax()));
                    txt_tax.setText("$" + amount);
                }

                if (payment.getPayeEmail() != null && !payment.getPayeEmail().equals("null")) {

                    txt_payee_email.setText(payment.getPayeEmail());
                }
                if (payment.getPayerEmail() != null && !payment.getPayerEmail().equals("null")) {

                    txt_payer_email.setText(payment.getPayerEmail());
                }

                if (payment.getPayerName() != null && !payment.getPayerName().equals("null")) {

                    txt_payer_name.setText(payment.getPayerName());
                }

                if (payment.getVendorId() != null && !payment.getVendorId().equals("null")) {

                    txt_vendor_id.setText(payment.getVendorId());
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

How can I achieve this? please help.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the variable i as a global variable and using `i++` inside the loop. So inside the `onClick` method the `if(i == 1)` is either always false, or always true.

Make variable local and use `myButton.setId(i);` inside your for loop where you create buttons.

Now inside `OnClickListener` you can use `int id = v.getId();` and use `if(id == 1)`

Comment: How this switch will work? I wont be knowing the size of array and how many buttons will be created it will be based on the data, so how to check the correct object in switch?

Comment: how in switch case?

Comment: @Sid what is happening with your code in the question and what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to show dynamic buttons as per list size and I want to show the data of list item on click of the button.

Comment: Now I tried to show the first items data by default and on click of button the data should change, but data dose not change .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156185/discussion-between-sid-and-nabin-bhandari).

Answer (score 0):

You can set an onClickLister to the button in that row which will have a reference to that row's data. Use an intent to start the detailed activity and add the clicked item's data as an extra.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

//Inflate your row

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    //On click function
    public void onClick(View view) {
         HashMap<String, String> item = contactsList.get(position);
         //Create the intent to start another activity
         Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
         intent.putExtra("data", item);
         view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
});
});
```

in the receiving activity, you can get the data from the intent

```
HashMap<String, String> data = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableExtra("data");
```

Comment: I dont have any intent, I am showing data on same fragment itself